# Defined variables not working in javascript files when I use getScript

Tags: jquery, variables

When I use `$.getScript` the variables in the main javascript file cannot pass to included js file. For example:

```
var tVar = 'Hello World!';
$.getScript('js/setting.js', function() {
    // My callback code
});
```

*setting.js*:

```
alert(tVar);
```

How can I pass variables to included file?

Answer (score 2):

May be use a function inside your included js file and pass variable as arguement to that function.

Answer (score 1):

The loaded script can only access global variables.

You've got two options:

1. Temporary create a global variable.
2. Call the injected function from within the callback.

Code for method 1:

```
var tVar = 'Hello World!';
$.getScript('js/setting.js');
window.get_tVar = function() {
    delete window.get_tVar; // Clean-up
    return tVar;
};
// In settings.js:
function logic() {
    var tVar = window.get_tVar();
}
```

Code for method 2:

```
var tVar = 'Hello World!';
$.getScript('js/setting.js', function() {
    newGlobalFunc(tVar);
});

// In settings.js:
function newGlobalFunc(tVar) {
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, to be honest I don't know why more people don't do this, but here's what I do

```
// settings.js

var com = {};
com.example = {};    

( function( $ ) {

    com.example.Main = function(){
        var private = {};
        var public = {};

        public.initialize = function( myVar ){
            alert( myVar );
        }

        return public;
    }()

})( jQuery );


// main 
var myVar = 'Hello World!';
$.getScript('js/setting.js', function() {
    com.example.Main.initialize( myVar );
});
```